# Espresso BaseMatcher matches method not looping through all the views on screen

Tags: android, android-espresso

Espresso BaseMatcher matches method not looping through all the views on screen
Instead it is looping through current window UI elements only

Example if i have an activity along with dialog window
it is looping through only dialog UI elements.

```
 new BaseMatcher<View>() {
             @Override
             public void describeTo(Description description) {
                 description.appendText(String.format("Looked for element with XPath %s", xpath));
             }

             @Override
             public boolean matches(Object item) {
                 //here I am checking for matched view inside activity
                 // the item is always from dialog
                 //activity views are not part of this matches method calls
                 return condition;
             }

         };
```

Comment: Can you add your espresso code, preferably as an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: @MDNaseemAshraf thanks
I have added my code of matcher